# How to add a device to developer.apple.com's account

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

When I went to archive my app, XCode showed me 3 errors showing in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Then I knew I have to add a device manually in my `developer.apple.com`'s account.

But the problem I don't have an Apple device.

**Is there a way I can publish my app in the app store without having an Apple device?**

Answer (score 0):

> **You can publish your build/app without having registered (your) device(s) in
> apple developer account.**
>
> Publish a build on App Store has no relation with registration of device into developer account. Apple does not check, whether there is any registered device in developer account or not, while publishing a build on app store. You can publish your build on app store without registering device with developer account.
>
> But I suggest, you should register your apple device(s) to apple developer account as it will allow you to debug your build in device and test your application.
>
> Behavior of certain features of application/iOS are not always same as in Simulator. So you should check/test your application in your iOS device once, prior to publish on store/beta testing.

Comment: Your information on how to add a device to a developer account would be useful if the OP hadn't stated in the post: "But the problem **I don't have an Apple device.**"

Comment: You say it is possible, but I don't find anywhere in your answer how to do it.

Comment: Publishing build on appstore and registration of device into developer account has no relation. Apple do not check whether there is any registered device in developer account or not, while publishing a build on app store. OP can publish its build on app store without registering its device (if he has) with developer account.

Comment: I agree. With that in mind, your answer would be extremely confusing since 95% of it is how to add a device to a developer profile. Maybe you should provide the steps for creating a distribution certificate and profile, and then how to build a release build with that signing identity.

Comment: No problem. I think part of the confusion comes from the poster's title for the question. In reality they are not asking to register a device, but rather how to build without an iOS device. I do agree that no one should publish an app to the store with only simulator testing, but maybe the OP is planning on doing some TestFlight beta testing.

Comment: Yes, I saw title first and focused on it rather than actual problem